# How can I get upper and lower limits in 1 line?

Tags: python-2.7

How can I get the `min` and `max` in one line?

```
d = {'k1': ['2000-01-01', '2003-01-01'],
     'k2': ['2001-01-01', '2003-01-21'],
     'k3': ['2001-11-01', '2002-01-01'],
}
d0 = min((a[0] for a in d.itervalues())) # '2000-01-01'
d1 = max((a[1] for a in d.itervalues())) # '2003-01-21'
```

Of course, the real dict is much longer than in this example. And of course too `d0, d1 = min(...), max(...)` is not the tricky I'm asking for :)

Comment: Did you mean # instead of %?

Comment: yes, thanks for correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reduce(lambda lst, val: [min(lst[0],val[0]), max(lst[1],val[1])],iter(d.itervalues()))
```

Comment: why add `iter()`? it gives the same results without `iter`